# CSS for styling the Blazor Project Templates in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, blazor

I can't seem to locate where the gradient (blue/purple) navbar styles are set in the Blazor Project Templates (Visual Studio 2022)

I can override it by setting style in NavMenu.razor file, but this doesn't seem to be the best approach. Can't find any nav-scrollable class in the app.css.

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu" style="background-color: red;">
```

[image]

app.css

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');

html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a, .btn-link {
    color: #0071c1;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn-link.nav-link:focus, .form-control:focus, .form-check-input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem white, 0 0 0 0.25rem #258cfb;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.validation-message {
    color: red;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

    #blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.75rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
    }

.blazor-error-boundary {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 1rem/1.8rem, #b32121;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3.7rem;
    color: white;
}

    .blazor-error-boundary::after {
        content: "En feil har oppstått."
    }

.loading-progress {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
    margin: 20vh auto 1rem auto;
}

    .loading-progress circle {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #e0e0e0;
        stroke-width: 0.6rem;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

        .loading-progress circle:last-child {
            stroke: #1b6ec2;
            stroke-dasharray: calc(3.141 * var(--blazor-load-percentage, 0%) * 0.8), 500%;
            transition: stroke-dasharray 0.05s ease-in-out;
        }

.loading-progress-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    inset: calc(20vh + 3.25rem) 0 auto 0.2rem;
}

    .loading-progress-text:after {
        content: var(--blazor-load-percentage-text, "Laster inn");
    }
```

When I run the application and do a "view source" from the webbrowser I can see a css file which is not found in my template project which has the css I'm looking for. Is this something that must be scaffolded?

https://localhost:7126/Server.Blazor.WebAssembly.Client.styles.css

```
/* /Shared/MainLayout.razor.rz.scp.css */
.page[b-95gffx9uy9] {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main[b-95gffx9uy9] {
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar[b-95gffx9uy9] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}

.top-row[b-95gffx9uy9] {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  a, .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  .btn-link {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  a:hover, .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  .btn-link:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  a:first-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
    .top-row:not(.auth)[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-row.auth[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  a, .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9]  .btn-link {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .sidebar[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-row.auth[b-95gffx9uy9]  a:first-child {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: right;
        width: 0;
    }

    .top-row[b-95gffx9uy9], article[b-95gffx9uy9] {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
/* /Shared/NavMenu.razor.rz.scp.css */
.navbar-toggler[b-jke5upsn2y] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.top-row[b-jke5upsn2y] {
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar-brand[b-jke5upsn2y] {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.oi[b-jke5upsn2y] {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    top: -2px;
}

.nav-item[b-jke5upsn2y] {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

    .nav-item:first-of-type[b-jke5upsn2y] {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item:last-of-type[b-jke5upsn2y] {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item[b-jke5upsn2y]  a {
        color: #d7d7d7;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 3rem;
    }

.nav-item[b-jke5upsn2y]  a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color: white;
}

.nav-item[b-jke5upsn2y]  a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler[b-jke5upsn2y] {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse[b-jke5upsn2y] {
        /* Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens */
        display: block;
    }
    
    .nav-scrollable[b-jke5upsn2y] {
        /* Allow sidebar to scroll for tall menus */
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for the component Css in `MainLayout.razor.css`

Line 11

```css
.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}
```

Other specific sidebar stuff is in NavMenu.razor.css.

These component files are all bundled on build into the project specific css file - your *Server.Blazor.WebAssembly.Client.styles.css*.  Each component has a specific ID - such as `b-95gffx9uy9`.

Comment: There it all is. Thank you. I didn't notice the .css files "bundled" with the .razor files.